# Once a form is submitted, how to create a user object

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

I am working on an assignment and need assistance with the next step in the process. I Understand how to create a User Object, but I am not fully understanding the questions. I am only seeking guidance, so I may learn as I go. They are asking me to create a user object once the form has been successfully submitted. Does this mean I need to create a new user class and put all the data members, properties and methods in there? Or do I stay in the static main void class and code these in there? Here is the question and the code I have so far. I will post the entire project, but highlight the area I am stuck at. Number 5 and 6 is where I am stuck at.

> 1. Create a user registration system.
> 2. It will need to contain the fields as shown in the screen shot. Form controls that the code will interact with need to have their names changed to something more meaningful. Do not leave textbox1 as textbox1.
> 3. The password and confirm password fields need to be matched against each other, both when the page is submitted and also when the confirm password field has lost focus. If the form is not valid then the page will not be processed as described below. The password fields need to mask the password.
> 4. The major is a combo box (DropDownList style) that will contain a list of majors (at least 5) of your choosing. Based upon the major selected you'll populate the items in the specialty drop down list below the major, for the user to select from those items.
> 5. **Once the form is successfully submitted we'll use the values in the form to create a user object
> 6. The user object will be composed of private data members plus properties, all the fields will be strings, with the exception of the major, which will be an enumeration.**
> 7. The clear button will reset the form to its initial empty state.
>      The load last button will repopulate the form with the last user object that was created, if no user object has been created, show a MessageBox with an error message indicating there is no data to load

```
namespace Forms
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void passwordTxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        passwordTxt.PasswordChar = 'x';
        passwordTxt.MaxLength = 11;
    }

    private void confPassTxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        confPassTxt.PasswordChar = 'x';
        confPassTxt.MaxLength = 11;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        majorBox.Items.Add("");
        majorBox.Items.Add("Math");
        majorBox.Items.Add("Science");
        majorBox.Items.Add("English");
        majorBox.Items.Add("Philosophy");
        majorBox.Items.Add("History");
    }

    private void submitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstNameTxt.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastNameTxt.Text)
           || string.IsNullOrEmpty(userNameTxt.Text) ||
           string.IsNullOrEmpty(passwordTxt.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(confPassTxt.Text)
           || string.IsNullOrEmpty(majorBox.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(specialtyBox.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must enter in all fields before moving forward");
        }
    }

    private void majorBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (majorBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Math")
        {
            specialtyBox.Items.Clear();
            specialtyBox.Items.Add("Calculus");
            specialtyBox.Items.Add("Statistics");
        }
        else if (majorBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Science")
        {
            specialtyBox.Items.Clear();
            specialtyBox.Items.Add("Biology");
            specialtyBox.Items.Add("Chemestry");
        }
        else if (majorBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "English")
        {
            specialtyBox.Items.Clear();
            specialtyBox.Items.Add("18th Centruy");
            specialtyBox.Items.Add("Teacher");
        }
        else if (majorBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Philosophy")
        {
            specialtyBox.Items.Clear();
            specialtyBox.Items.Add("Aristotal");
            specialtyBox.Items.Add("Socrates");
        }
        else
        {
            specialtyBox.Items.Clear();
            specialtyBox.Items.Add("Peace");
            specialtyBox.Items.Add("War");
        }
    }

    private void confPassTxt_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (confPassTxt.Text != passwordTxt.Text)
        {
            wrongPass.SetError(confPassTxt, "Worng password");
        }
        else
        {
            wrongPass.SetError(confPassTxt, "");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should ask only one question at a time, adding what you've tried, and why it's not working.

Comment: I am just unclear as to if I need to create another class or not? if I could get that question answered I can move forward and do the assignment and post what I do produce if it fails. your help is appreciated. @B.ClayShannon

Comment: you should create a registration class also where is the `Screen Shot` we can't see it here...

Answer (score 0):

You just have to define a user class:

```
class User {
    private int id;
    private string name;
    private string job;
    ...
}
```

and then in your `submitBtn_Click` method after some validations just create a new instance of User class:

```
private void submitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstNameTxt.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastNameTxt.Text)
           || string.IsNullOrEmpty(userNameTxt.Text) ||
           string.IsNullOrEmpty(passwordTxt.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(confPassTxt.Text)
           || string.IsNullOrEmpty(majorBox.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(specialtyBox.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must enter in all fields before moving forward");

        } else {
            User userObj = new User();
        }
}
```

also you should put a constructor in your user class to fill the User class members.

EDIT:

Ok, you should erase that `private string confPassword;` line in your class definition, because it's just a validation field. Also the major field should be numeric because the id of major should be store in database.

```
 class Members
 {
    private string firstName;
    private string lastName;
    private string userName;
    private string password;
    private int major;
    private int specialty;

    public Members(string firstName, string lastName, string userName,string password, int major, int specialty)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
        this.major = major;
        this.specialty = specialty;
    }
}
```

then you should have something like this in your Form Class under Submit_Click method.

```
   else
        {
            Members user = new Members(firstNameStrVal, lastNameStrVal, userNameStrVal, passwordStrVal, majorIntVal, specialtyIntVal);
            ....
            your database insert will be here
        }
```

Now user object contains the Form data and ready for database transactions.